# Number of tuples

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I am given N numbers a[1..N] and 2 other integers L and H. How can I Count the number of tuples (i,j,k) satisfying i < j < k and L <= a[i] + a[j] + a[k] <= H.

```
1 <= T <= 100
1 <= N <= 1000
1 <= L <= H <= 1000000
1 <= a[i] <= 1000000
```

PS: Need Better Solution than N2logn

Comment: Within a reasonable time limit? Is T the number of tuples?

Comment: Have you tried a brute force approach?  Sometimes it's a good starting point for algorithm design.

Comment: @corlettk, Time Limit Exceeded. It's a term for Online Judges. It's Programming Challenge Question. :)

Comment: Ok so YOUR challenge is to dream-up a way of eliminating impossibilities (tuples which cannot meet the requirements) quickly... and quickly usually means avoiding considering chunks of tuples... How could you do that? PS: Could you please post a link to the challenge?

Comment: Isn't this a variation of the 3SUM problem? :\

Comment: smells like dynamic programming

Comment: @st0le: No, 3SUM asks for the three values added up to **equal** another value (usually `0`). This asks for inequality. You can *decide* whether there is a triple in this case in `O(n log(n))`.

Comment: @OP Who are you trying to fool? this is an exact same question currently in ICPC amrita regional.

Comment: Please post a link to the challenge.

Comment: Please don't post contest questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution**

Since my C/C++ is somewhat rusty and this is primarily an algorithms question, I will write in pseudocode (mostly correct C/C++ with bits of algorithms that would take a while to write out).

If you have at least sizeof(int)*10^12 bytes of memory and time available, you can use this algorithm with time complexity O(n^2 * log(n)).

```
// Sort the N numbers using your favorite, efficient sorting method. (Quicksort, mergesort, etc.) [O(n*log(n))].
int[] b = sort(a)
int[] c = int[length(b)^2];
// Compute the sums of all of the numbers (O(n^2))
for(int i = 0; i < length(b); i++){
    for (int j = i; j < length(b); j++){
        c[i*length(b)+j] = b[i]+b[j];
    }
}

// Sort the sum list (you can do the sorts in-place if you are comfortable) - O(n^2*log(n))
d = sort(c);

// For each number in your list, grab the list of of sums so that L<=num+sum<=H O(n)
// Use binary search to find the lower, upper bounds O(log(n))
// (Total complexity for this part: O(n*log(n))
int total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < b; i++){
    int min_index = binary_search(L-b[i]); // search for largest number <= L-b[i]
    int max_index = binary_search(H-b[i]); // search for smallest number >= H-b[i]
    total += max_index - min_index + 1; // NOTE: This does not handle edge cases like not finding any sums that work
}

return total;
```

Comment: Hey Steve, There's no point in doing programming challenges if you don't do them (or least the crux of them) yourself... so I personally try to avoid giving handouts, or even too-big-hints, until the questioner admits to being stuck, and has evidently invested a lot of effort on their own behalf... then we (the community) become collaberators, not spoilers. Just my personal opinion.

Comment: Hm, I'm fairly new to posting in this community, so I was wondering about this particular site in general- is the point of StackOverflow to be like "homework help" forums, where you only guide but do not give the answers?

The way I've used this forum was for questions that I needed answered, preferably as fast as possible, so I appreciated full answers; I tend to avoid StackOverflow (and certain other resources) for puzzles that I wanted to solve myself.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a[i] +a[j]

Comment: The size of `c` is `n^2` so the time to sort it is `O(n^2log(n^2))`

Comment: Oh yuck... some more optimization needed then.

Comment: To me, "the right answer" depends on the motivations of the person asking the question... and I personally think that posting "complete algorithms" is counterproductuve where the point of the exercise WAS to make the questioner think it through in order to come-up with there own algorithm to solve an otherwise pointless problem... giving them priceless practice in developing there own algorithms, which is NOT an easy skill to learn, and certainly won't happen (for most of us) overnight.

Comment: Ah fair enough. Given that my algorithm is flawed and the OP has already seen it, I think I'll leave it up but not fix it for now.

(As an aside, I didn't realize this was a programming challenge until I read your comment and then scrolled up.)

Comment: I'll only give "major" help on challenges when the questioner is evidently completely stuck, and therefore the challenge would otherwise for them be a negative (confidence depreciating) experience... which it will be anyway if someone else CAN just hand you "the answer".

Comment: Programming challenges have a "smell" to them... you're a very very capable programmer, and I therefore know you're highly intelligent, and therefore trust that you'll learn to spot them "off the bat".

Comment: @fgb, `O(n^2log(n^2))` is the same as `O((n^2) log n)` because `log(n^2) = 2 log n`.

Comment: When you look for sums `L<=num+sum<=H`, I think you also take sums, which already include `num`, (`num = a[i]`, `sum = a[i] + a[k]`), or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 1):

A basic approach:

```
for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
    for (j=i+1; j<N; j++) {
        for (k=j+1; k<N; k++) {
            int sum = a[i] + a[j] + a[k];
            if (L <= sum && sum <= H) number_of_tuples++;
        }
    }
}
```

Possibly better (might have a mistake in it, but the basic idea is to break if you're already over the maximum):

```
for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
    if (a[i] > H) continue;
    for (j=i+1; j<N; j++) {
        if (a[i] + a[j] > H) continue;
        for (k=j+1; k<N; k++) {
            int sum = a[i] + a[j] + a[k];
            if (L <= sum && sum <= H) number_of_tuples++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @onefoot, I upvoted it because it's a valid starting point... did you run it? How long does it take for the given limits?

Comment: No, I haven't run it; I just put it down as a baseline.

Comment: @onefoot... Yup, that's getting better!

Answer (score 1):

```
int find_three(int arr[], int c, int l,int h)
{
   int i, j, e, s, k;
   int count =0;
   sort(arr,arr+c);
   c--;
   while(arr[c]>h)
   c--;
   int sum=0;
   for (int i = 0; i<=c-2;i++)
   {  sum=arr[i]+arr[i+1]+arr[i+2];
      if(sum>h)
      break;
      for(j=i+1;j<=c-1;j++)
       {  
          for(k=j+1;k<=c;k++)
          {   sum=arr[i]+arr[j]+arr[k];
              if(sum>=l &&sum<=h)
                 count++;
              if(sum>h)
              break;
          }
           if(sum>h)
              break;
       }
   }
      return  count;
}
```