# Finding Triplets in a array with sum within a range

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Number of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216041/number-of-tuples)

Given N numbers `a[1..N]` and 2 other integers L and H, we have to count number of tuples `(i,j,k)` such that `L <= a[i] + a[j] + a[k] <= H`.
Can this be done in better than `O(n^3)`?
Any suggestions/ algorithms?

Comment: Some university has homework due Monday... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216041/number-of-tuples

Comment: No the numbers are not sorted.

Comment: Output size is O(n^3) so it's a bit hard to do any faster...

Comment: @n.m. The question only asks for the count, so output size is O(1).

Comment: @john Ah missed that. It should be a bit easier then.

Comment: Another attempt to avoid work here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13217120/to-reduce-the-complexity-of-n3-to-n2

Answer (score 0):

first sort a[i] to increasing order.

enumerate a[i] and a[j], so you can use [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to find how many a[k] satisfies L - (a[i] + a[j]) <= a[k] <= H - (a[i] + a[j]).

the whole algorithm cost `O(n^2*log(n))`