# Finding a triplet in an array of floating pointer numbers that sum to a value in [1.0, 2.0]

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

The problem is:

> Given an array of floating pointer numbers, find 3 numbers (not necessarily contiguous) that sum to a value bounded by the interval [1.0, 2.0]

This problem was posted here [Triplet whose sum in range (1,2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19557505/triplet-whose-sum-in-range-1-2) and also https://www.thetopsites.net/article/50729117.shtml.

The algorithm in the latter link appears to be identical to the algorithm posted by @Amitrajit Bose in the stackoverflow question. This algorithm essentially uses a greedy approach that discards the largest of the current set of 3 numbers you're considering if the sum is > 2.0 and replaces it with the current number in the array, and if the sum is < 1.0, it replaces the smallest number in the current set of 3 numbers.

This algorithm seems wrong? Consider [0.2 0.2 1.7 0.5 0.05 0.05]. There are several solutions in this case and they must each use 1.7, but this algorithm would the number 1.7 and conclude that it is not possible to find a triplet under the given constraints.

Am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right. Such algorithm is wrong, you just provided a test case where it fails.

Mentioned algorithm:

```
1> Prepare the window of size 3 with the first 3 elements
2> IF (array.len <= 3): CHECK IF window-sum is in the range (1,2), then RETURN accordingly
3> FOR i = 3 UPTO (array.len-1)
3.1> SORT the window (3log3 = constant time operation)
3.2> IF window-sum is in the range (1,2): RETURN 1 or TRUE
3.3> ELSE IF window-sum < 1: Replace the smallest element in the window (window[0]) with array[i]
3.4> ELSE IF window-sum > 2: Replace the largest element in the window (window[2]) with array[i]
4> Outside the loop, check the FINAL window sum and RETURN accordingly.
```

Another counterexample: `[0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 1.5]`
First window is `[0.2, 0.3, 0.4]`. The `for` loop starts and ends at index `3` where `window_sum = 0.9 < 1`. Step `3.3` is taken so next window is `[0.3, 0.4, 1.5]` where `window_sum = 2.2 > 2`. The algorithm ends claiming that there is no such triplet whose sum is in `[1.0, 2.0]`. Such claim is false as `(0.2, 0.3, 1.5)` sums `2.0`.

Side note: There are a few more incorrect answers in that stackoverflow question.